# Get last post date for custom post type - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, date, custom-post-type

This is probably a simple one but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

I have 2 custom post types. I display them in sections on my home page.

In each section I'd like to have "Last Updated [DATE]" text near the title for each section.

I've found `<?php get_lastpostdate( $timezone ) ?>` but is there a way of specifying which post type you'd like to query?

**[UPDATE]**

Here's the final code I used based on Howdy_McGee's answer below. I wanted the date to read as "16th May" for example.
`Thanks, that's the route I started to go down as well. I guess I was hoping to not do another WP_Query, but it works. This is the final code I used:

```
<p class="right last-update"><?php 
    $latest = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'car', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'orderby' => 'modified', 'order' => 'ASC'));
    if($latest->have_posts()){
        $modified_date = $latest->posts[0]->post_modified;
    }
    //Get the last post update and display the date as "10th March"
    $lastpost = strtotime($modified_date);
    $lastmonth = date('F', $lastpost);
    $lastday = date('jS', $lastpost);
    echo 'Last Updated '.$lastday.' '.$lastmonth;
    ?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`the_post_modified()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_date) if you're in The Loop. The modified date will change any time the post is changed in any way / updated in any way.

**Update**

Ok, lets run a small query, what this does is pulls the latest post, modified or new. Since it's just 1 post we can just check if it has posts, and get the first posts modified date.

```
<?php 
    $latest = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'car',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'orderby' => 'modified',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        )
    );

    if($latest->have_posts()){
        $modified_date = $latest->posts[0]->post_modified;
    }
?>
```

For a full list of [Date Format Options, View Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time). If you're using it outside The Loop, you can use [`get_the_modified_date()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_modified_date). Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Just so I'm clear, I'd like to just display one date that changes when any post of a certain type are changed, not a modified date with each post. I would like to use it outside the loop. Basically I'm unclear how I would get the modified date for a specific post type e.g my custom post type called "car". Do you have any hints on that?

Comment: So what you're doing is, if Any post in post type `car` is added or modified, you want to display the date of the added / modified post?

Comment: Try that. The query orders all the posts in that post type by a modified date, which includes new posts and we only pull the newest, most recently modified post.

Comment: Thanks, that's the route I started to go down as well. I guess I was hoping to not do another WP_Query, but it works.

Comment: It should be `'order' => 'DESC'`

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar for a site I was working on and adapted your code slightly if this helps anyone else

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'book'; // or post
$latest = new WP_Query(
        array(
        'post_type' => $taxonomy,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'modified',
        'order' => 'DESC'));
if($latest->have_posts()){
echo 'Last Updated ' . mysql2date('jS F Y', $latest->posts[0]->post_modified);
}
?>
```

This shows the last modified date of the post_type selected

Update: just realised that someone else posted this answer, I only looked at the 1st post "update", but, meh